# How to code Distance Sensor Application in arduino

Tags: arduino

```
#define trigPin 4
#define echoPin 2

long sure, mesafe

void setup () {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);

    Serial.println("Arduino İle Mesafe Sensörü Uygulaması Başlatılıyor...");

    delay(3000);    
}

void loop () {
    digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(3);

    digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(10);
    digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);

    sure = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);
    mesafe = (sure/2) * 0.0343;

    Serial.print(mesafe);
    Serial.println(" cm uzaklıkta");
 
    delay(500);
}
```

Every time I run the code it gives me:

> 4:1: error: expected initializer before 'void'
>
> In function 'void loop()':
>
> 18:1: error: 'mesafe' was not declared in this scope
>
> 18:1: note: suggested  alternative: 'rename'

Answer (score 0):

There should be a  semicolon on the end of the line `long sure, mesafe`